# Haskell- how do I walk and compare down the Array/List

Tags: list, haskell

I am New to Haskell, but Veteran in some other languages.
(This question was taken from an Assembly language exercise, but I would like to solve it in Haskell.It is not part of homework or a test question)

Given:
 An array (list) which has the values inside the list follow this pattern:

The first item is smaller than the second item, the second item is greater than the third item, the third item is smaller than the fourth item and so on, (a "wave").

Questions:

1 How do I solve it in Haskell?
(I know how to solve it in other languages where I can handle the array indices, but I do not know how to how solve it with a functional language.

2. Can the answer be generalized so it can solve other patterns?

Comment: How about you try to solve it and post specific questions about which part of the attempted solution confused you or caused trouble?  Getting a point solution for one question probably won't help you learn the language to a significant degree.

Comment: 1. I forgot to mention that the question is asking for a function that will test whether the Array follows the "wave Pattern". 2.This is a general question: How do you check for a specific attribute of an item in a list without using loop and array indices?

Comment: 1. If you forgot something, you can edit the question, instead of adding new information in the comments. 2. You use recursion and pattern matching (or one of the many standard functions like `map,foldr,filter` which are the closest thing to "loops"). If you are a beginner in Haskell, learn pattern matching as soon as possible. Tutorials usually cover it early, since that's extremely important in Haskell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking questions on StackOverflow is not a good way to learn the bare basics of a new programming language. A tutorial or book will introduce these in a more structured manner.

Answer (score 7):

This can be quite easily expressed in Haskell

```
wave :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
wave xs = and $ zipWith3 ($) (cycle [(<),(>)]) xs (tail xs)
```

We could also trivially parametrise it on the patterns

```
waveLike :: [(a -> a -> Bool)] -> [a] -> Bool
waveLike patterns xs = and $ zipWith3 ($) (cycle patterns) xs (tail xs)

twoUpTwoDown :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
twoUpTwoDown = waveLike [(<),(<),(>),(>)]

coprimeThenNotCoprime :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Bool
coprimeThenNotCoprime = waveLike [coprime, notCoprime]
  where coprime m n = gcd m n == 1
        notCoprime m n = not (coprime m n)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that these functions, that you used , exist.

Answer (score 6):

Probie's is a very elegant solution, but perhaps a basic recursion can be more understandable for a beginner.

```
wave :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
wave []            = True
wave [_]           = True
wave [x1,x2]       = x1 < x2
wave (x1:x2:x3:xs) = x1 < x2 && x2 > x3 && wave (x3:xs)
```

The four lines of code read as follows:

A list with 0 elements is wavy.

A list with 1 element is wavy.

A list with 2 elements is wavy iff it is increasing.

A list with at least 3 elements starting with `x1,x2,x3` is wavy iff

1. we go "up" between `x1` and `x2`,
2. we go "down" between `x2` and `x3`,
3. the list from `x3` onward (including `x3`) is wavy.

Comment: As a matter of style, you could also write `wave (x1 : x2 : xs@(x3 : _)) = x1 < x2 && x2 > x3 && wave xs` since you’re just matching & rebuilding `x3 : xs`.